# Javascript - вырезать от тега до тега на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ячейка в таблице на странице, обозначенная :

```
<td class="Unmodified">text</td>
```

Как можно на javascript или jquery удалить все внутри данного td, включая открытие и закрытие ячейки?

Возможно через document.body.innerHTML.replace ?

Comment: что имеется ввиду под " включая открытие и закрытие ячейки"

Comment: Удалить все вместе с тегами <td class="Unmodified">text</td>

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно вас понял, вам нужно удалить ячейку целиком. Можно использовать метод `remove`

```
document.querySelector('.Unmodified').remove()
```

Если нужно удалить все ячейки с классом, то действий чуть побольше

```
document.querySelectorAll('.Unmodified').forEach( e => e.remove() )

// если нет forEach для querySelectorAll
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.Unmodified')
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    elements[i].remove()
```

**UPD** 
[Полифил](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) `remove` для старичков

```
// from:https://github.com/jserz/js_piece/blob/master/DOM/ChildNode/remove()/remove().md
(function (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('remove')) {
      return;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(item, 'remove', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: function remove() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      }
    });
  });
})([Element.prototype, CharacterData.prototype, DocumentType.prototype]);
```

Comment: `forEach` для результата `querySelectorAll` не во всех браузерах реализован

Comment: $('.Unmodified').each(function(){
     $(this).remove();
    });

Comment: Ещё и `remove` не во всех браузерах))

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавил еще и полифил)

Comment: Добавлять полифил самому айтему в цикле - что-то так себе идея...

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему? Мы же в прототип добавляем метод, что бы потом все элементы могли его использовать

Comment: Ой.. Я невнимательный... Тогда, наверное, верно.